# iScroll, How to detect when user has scrolled to bottom?

Tags: jquery, iscroll4, iscroll

Is there a way to detect when the user is at the bottom of the page using **iScroll v4?**

Answer (score 0):

It's not built in, but here's a simple way to add a callback when scrolling past the end..
(looking at https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/blob/master/src/iscroll.js)

declare a new event (Line 139)

```
onScrollLimit: null
```

then call it in the _move function (Line 490)

```
if (newY<that.maxScrollY) that.options.onScrollLimit.call(that, e);
```

and also call it in the _startAni function (Line 768)

```
if (step.y<that.maxScrollY) that.options.onScrollLimit.call(that);
```

The downside for last bit is that it will fire the event as it begins the animation (when you throw the scroll area), not if it physically goes past the end. Otherwise it's very tricky to tell when using css transitions.

Then all you have to do is add this to your options when you set up iScroll

```
myScroll = new iScroll('view', {onScrollLimit: function(){
    console.log("I've past the end!");
}});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can detect when the scrolling ends by using the 'onScrollEnd' listening.

Example:

```
var thingScroll = new iScroll('thing', {
        vScroll: false,
        hScrollbar: true,
        snap: '.page',
        bounce: true,
        inertia: false,

        onScrollEnd: function() {

                          //do stuff

        } 
    });
```

I believe this will let you know when it hits the bottom (or the bottom snap area), and if you want to be more specific try you can use the thingScroll.x and thingScroll.y methods and some jquery math to personally configure it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: onScrollEnd doesn't tell you when it hits the bottom. It tells you when iScroll has stopped scrolling.